# Ways to handle security/authorization in a multi tenant API

Tags: api, security, authorization, ravendb

I'm playing around with a spare time project, mainly to try out new stuff :)

This involves designing a REST API for a system that is multi tenant. Lets say you have an "organization" that is the "top" entity, this might have an API key assigned that is used for authenticating each request. So on each request we have an organization associated.

Now when a user of the API would like to get a list of, lets say projects, only those that belong to that organization should be returned. The actual implementation, the queries to the database, is pretty straight forward. However the approach is interesting I think.

You could implement the filtering each time you query the database, but a better approach would be a general pre-query applied to all "organization" related queries, like all queries for enities that belong to an organization. It's all about avoiding the wrong entities from being returned. You could isolate the database, but if that is not possible how would you approach it?

Right now I use NancyFX and RavenDB so input for that stack would be appreciated, but general ideas and best practices, do's and don't is very welcome.

Comment: Have you considered just using a separate database per tenant?  RavenDB supports multiple databases per server, as long as you aren't using the embedded version.

Comment: +1 for separate databases. Having multiple tenants in a a single database has two big downsides. Firstly added complexity - almost every piece of code you write is going to have to consider the multiple tenancy. Secondly Risk - there is an ongoing risk that data for one tenant will accidentally be displayed to another tenant.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could isolate your collections by prefixing them with the organization_id. It will duplicate maybe many collections.

Use case with mongodb: http://support.mongohq.com/use-cases/multi-tenant.html